# Unsupported CSS selector '*[name='username']'. Reason: 'Error: 'name' is not a valid attribute - Appium PageFactory

Tags: appium, page-factory

**Hi all!**

I've been having the next issue:
I'm trying to use PageFactory in my appium project, but haven't been able.

```
public class LoginPageObjects {

AppiumDriver driver;

@AndroidFindBy(id = "username")
public WebElement username;
@AndroidFindBy(id = "password")
public WebElement passwordElement;
@AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.view.ViewGroup[@content-desc=\"loginBtn\"]/android.widget.TextView\n")
public WebElement buttonElement;

public LoginPageObjects(AppiumDriver driver){
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);
}

public void setUsernameTextBox(String text){
    username.sendKeys(text);
}

public void setPasswordTextBox(String text){
    passwordElement.sendKeys(text);
}

public void clickLoginButton() {
    passwordElement.click();
}
}
```

It's not working this way, having the following error calling username.sendKeys():

```
 Unsupported CSS selector '*[name='username']'. Reason: 'Error: 'name' is not a valid attribute.
```

where I have also tried

```
PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver),this);
```

But this throws a new error

Currently using:

io.appium 8.0.0;
org.seleniumhq.selenium 4.1.3;
JDK v18

Pst: PageFactory in Selenium with the same versions is working fine.

Comment: I may be mistaken.. But I think there needs to be a '@' before 'name'

Comment: @rayad How would you do it?

Comment: I think '*[name='username']' might need to be '*[@name='username']'.